# How to set up a mercurial repository which contains only some packages from different subrepositories projects?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I have a distant repository called http://myrepo

I also have 3 projects with 3 distinct packages (1 in each) stored in `D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]`.

I would like to create a local repo in `D:/Mercurial` which will reference the packages `pack[ABC]` as subrepositories, which are to be pushed to my distant repo.

Finally, I would like to have my packages stored in my distant repo so you read http://myrepo/pack[ABC], and they should reflect the changes made in `D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]`.

I can't manage tu push my subrepositories to my distant one. How to set-up such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your subrepos in your top repo's .hgsub as:

LocalPathA = http://server/A

LocalPathB = http://server/B

LocalPathC = http://server/C

Then, on Server, you will have to create empty repositories (with appropriate permissions) A, B, C

Your local repositories A,B,C will need their [paths] default=http://server/A, etc set up.

### hgrc for the subs

```
[paths]
default = source repo
```

### hgsub for the surrounding repo

protocol://servername//absolute/path/to/repo  = relative/path/from/surrounding/repo/root

Comment: I got the following message:

`D:\Projects>hg commit -m "Adding subrepositories"
abort: The syntax of the filename, directory or volume is incorrect:
D:\Projects\http://myrepo/B`

Comment: Ow OK... I just noticed the last part, I'll try that!

Comment: I added `[paths]
default = http://myrepo/[ABC]` in the hgrc file of my repos `D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]`. I still get the same error

Comment: I put `https://mydistantrepo/[ABC] = D:/Projects/Projact[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]` in my main repo .hgsub and `[paths]
default = D:/Projects/Project[ABC]/src/pack[ABC]` in my projects' .hgrc, and I still have the same pb: Mercurial tries to add the distant URL to my current CMD directory. There is something I still don't get there...

Comment: @user: you have to use paths relative to your repo root in hg sub. I really suggest you study the hg man page here.

Comment: The thing I don't get is that Mercurial tries to add the distant repos' URL to my current directory i.e. `D:\Projects\http://mydistantrepo/[ABC]`. Since my hgsub is `distant = local`, making the `local` be relative rather than absolute doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: .hgsubs are in the form local_path = distant, by definition.

Comment: Look at your answer: You told me the exact opposite.

And if it is to come back to the old local = distant, my projects are pushed to my local subdirectories and not to my distant repo.....

Back to the beginning?